# make CSS corner style

Tags: html, css

I am confused, how to make the design of display options like this with css :

[image: this]

how to make corner style like this picture ... please help me. thanks

Comment: Do you mean to say the border style?

Comment: I think OP is talking about the [arrow](http://www.cssarrowplease.com/).

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Either way not a very clear question. Please elaborate on what you want and also what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks Maharkus... that is what I mean ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.inner{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.outer{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.arrow{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: -50px;
 border: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 25px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class='arrow'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/pksdhofc/1/

```
<div class='arrow'></div>

.arrow{
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #999;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
}
```

clip-path uses multiple X and Y coords to create an svg. You can minipulate as you like but that kinda makes what you need.

Comment: Using `clip-path` will seriously limit your browser support, you'd be better off with the old border hack that everyone uses.

Comment: Why so complicated. we can use borders anytime to create arrows like these

Comment: First thing I thought of. And if we all put in the effort, we can forget about IE 9 and 10 :). @nikamanish It's not really complicated. Your's is better, yes